# Can't Connect To Apache Web Server

Tags: php, html, windows, apache, wamp

So I've been trying to host a website on my Windows 10 server using WAMP, and almost have it working.

The link I'm trying to use is www.lesboizs.club, and I've setup the Apache v-hosts file, as well as created the HTML files for the website. If I change the "hosts" file in system32 of windows so that lesboizs.club forwards back to the computer, I can access the site no problem. I believe that means Apache is setup right. I also know that my DNS and port forwarding is all good, I used a Minecraft server set to port 80 to test it all out, and was able to connect to the server using lesboizs.club:80, so I know that's set up right. I also know that Apache is listening on port 80, and nothing else is, because I checked it with `netstat -n -a -o -p TCP`

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I'm totally stumped, and happy to provide any necessary information.

Comment: can't connect from where?

Comment: Where are you trying to access it from? And what do see? access denied? Timed out?

Comment: Timed out. Can't connect from local network or from external network.